# Understanding MuleSoft flow transformation

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am new to MuleSoft and Mule flows.

I want to concatenate the `fromairport` and `toairport` columns. The result should be in columns like:

```
fromairport           toairport

MUA                        LAX

MUA                        CLE

MUA                        SFO

.....
```

I am transforming the following json:

```
    [
      {
        "planeType": "Boeing 787",
        "code2": "0001",
        "takeOffDate": "2016-01-20T00:00:00",
        "code1": "rree",
        "fromAirport": "MUA",
        "price": 541,
        "seatsAvailable": 0,
        "toAirport": "LAX",
        "ID": 1,
        "airlineName": "American Airlines",
        "totalSeats": 200
      },
      {
        "planeType": "Boeing 747",
        "code2": "0123",
        "takeOffDate": "2016-01-25T00:00:00",
        "code1": "eefd",
        "fromAirport": "MUA",
        "price": 300,
        "seatsAvailable": 7,
        "toAirport": "CLE",
        "ID": 2,
        "airlineName": "American Airlines",
        "totalSeats": 345
      },
      {
        "planeType": "Boeing 777",
        "code2": "0192",
        "takeOffDate": "2016-01-20T00:00:00",
        "code1": "ffee",
        "fromAirport": "MUA",
        "price": 300,
        "seatsAvailable": 0,
        "toAirport": "LAX",
        "ID": 3,
        "airlineName": "American Airlines",
        "totalSeats": 300
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question is correctly expressed. There is no concept of 'columns' as such in DataWeave. There are objects, arrays and attributes. The equivalent of a column is an attribute array of objects. You can see the same concept in the input JSON, where planeType, code2, etc. are the 'columns'.

I will assume you want this output not in JSON or XML, but you want to further process it, so the best match for the output should be application/java.

In Mule 4.x the DataWeave script is:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload map (
    $.fromAirport ++ " to " ++ $.toAirport
)
```

UPDATE: Based on the comments I have updated the script to return a list of strings. Each string is the concatenation of the fromAirport attribute, the literal string " to " and the toAirport attributes. Both attributes are expected to be strings.

Output:

```
["MUA to LAX", "MUA to CLE", "MUA to LAX"]
```

Comment: Thanks Aled. this is good, but i need to concatinate the 'fromairport' and 'toairport'

Comment: Can you please clarify in the question the expected result? It seems to imply that you expect the output to be 2 columns and it is not nowhere clear where the concatenation should be. Also, do you mean to concatenate the 2 strings?

Comment: my expectation is: concatinate 'fromAirport' to 'toAirport'. the result will be MUA to LAX, MUA to CLE, MUA to SFO

Comment: I'm confused too. In your question, you have posted you said 'the result should be in columns' (and you show your expected output). Now you are saying something different. Please edit your question and explain _exactly_ what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

Try output the payload to csv format

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator=" "
---
payload map ((item) -> {
    fromAirport: item.fromAirport,
    toairport: item.toAirport
})
```

Result:

```
fromAirport toairport
MUA LAX
MUA CLE
MUA LAX
```

You can try on Mulesoft Datawave playground [here](https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/playground)